# netplan/udevadm broken in Ubuntu 22 LXC containers

Tags: networking, systemd, netplan, udev, lxc

The physical host is running 18.04.6 LTS and LXD/LXC 3.0.3. I have two unprivileged containers, one Ubuntu 18.04 container and a new Ubuntu 22.04 container. (Using the default images that `lxc launch` provides.)

LXD is configured to use a bridged network (for direct container exposure to the external network so that I can manage the network with `netplan`). Setting up the network using LXD profile settings is undesirable as we have systems that rely on `netplan` within the container that move ip aliases between different hosts on the network.

`netplan` works fine in the Ubuntu 18.04 container, but due to `udevadm trigger` returning errors in the Ubuntu 22.04 container (which `netplan` relies on), `netplan` fails there.

Running `netplan apply` gives me the following errors:

```
eth0: Failed to write 'change' to '/sys/devices/virtual/net/eth0/uevent': Permission denied
...etc...
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['udevadm', 'trigger', '--attr-match=subsystem=net']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

It seems that the root of the problem is that `udevadm trigger` is busted.

The issue I'm running into appears to be the same issue experienced here:

https://discuss.linuxcontainers.org/t/no-ipv4-on-arch-linux-containers/6395/23

I have tried the things discussed in the above conversation.

Creating this file in the container:

`/etc/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.service.d/lxc.conf`:

```
[Service]
BindReadOnlyPaths=/sys
```

Tried adding this to the container configs:

```
lxc.mount.auto: sys
```

And later this:

```
lxc.mount.auto = proc:rw sys:ro
```

I also tried setting `security.nesting` to "true".

None of this seems to help.

I see another user experiencing a similar issue with using `netplan` in a Ubuntu 22 LXC container here:

https://discuss.linuxcontainers.org/t/unable-to-utilize-wireless-adapter-in-a-container/18176

It seems they just gave up on `netplan` after nobody was able to offer any solutions.

`netplan` is used on the physical host to configure the network and the `netplan` YAML configuration looks like this:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp1s0f0:
      dhcp4: false
  bridges:
    br0:
      interfaces: [enp1s0f0]
      addresses: [10.100.7.2/16]
      gateway4: 10.100.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8,1.1.1.1]
      parameters:
        stp: true
        forward-delay: 0
```

The `netplan` YAML file on the Ubuntu 22 container that produces the error looks like this (public IPs masked here):

```
network:
        version: 2
        ethernets:
                eth0:
                        dhcp4: false
                        addresses: [108.x.x.195/24]
                        routes:
                        - to: default
                          via: 108.x.x.1
                        nameservers:
                                addresses: [8.8.8.8,1.1.1.1]
```

Not super relevant though, since any `netplan` YAML config will produce the same error, even an "empty" one:

```
#
```

(Providing these irrelevant details upon request... since `netplan` is just completely broken when running an Ubuntu 22.04 container on a Ubuntu 18.04 physical host.)

I can get the Ubuntu 22 container on the network by manually running the following inside the container (public IPs masked):

```
ip addr add 108.x.x.195/24 dev eth0
ip route add 108.x.x.1 dev eth0
ip route add default via 108.x.x.1
```

Possibly related: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/14060

UPDATE: I also tried the following things:

- Upgrading LXD from 3.0.3 to 5.x (didn't help)
- Ubuntu 20.04 container on Ubuntu 18.04 host (works fine, but not helpful since I need a 22.04 container)
- Ubuntu 22.04 container on Ubuntu 20.04 host (works fine)

So, my current plan is to upgrade all physical hosts to 20.04 or 22.04 (which was already on my task list anyway, but we were hoping to upgrade all containers first).

Comment: @user535733, thanks for your interest in my question. I've updated my post to include the specific Ubuntu versions I'm using.  I found a discussion that seems to address the issue and I've added that link above, but the solutions don't work here. I'm not having any issues with getting the network online using `ip addr`.  The issue I'm trying to address here is that `netplan apply` triggers this error regardless of what network configuration is used.

Comment: @user535733, I have a pretty plain vanilla setup other than wanting to make network changes from within the container using `netplan`. Networking is not an issue as far as I can tell, it's just that `netplan apply` isn't able to run due to the reliance on `udevadm trigger`, which appears broken when running in the described environment.  Is your test environment Ubuntu 18.04 on the physical host running LXD/LXC 3.0.3 and running Ubuntu 22.04 on an unprivileged container?  You can run `udevadm trigger` without errors?

Comment: @user535733, I'm not sure what information you're asking for. I just now added that I've got LXD configured to use bridged networking (but I figured that would be obvious since my environment requires managing the network from inside the container).  I think you're saying that you're not using a bridged network and that you're managing the network outside of the container, which is the reason you can't reproduce this.

Comment: We have systems that rely on `netplan` within the container, and so using LXD profiles is undesirable. I added the details you requested (along with other discoveries I made). It looks like I'll need to upgrade all physical hosts to at least Ubuntu 20.04 to resolve this.